# How do you get Unmanaged<CGColorSpace> from CGColorSpace?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, vimage

I am writing a function in Swift that creates a `vImage_CGImageFormat` from a `CGImage` as follows:

```
vImage_CGImageFormat(
    bitsPerComponent: UInt32(CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image)), 
    bitsPerPixel: UInt32(CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(image)), 
    colorSpace: CGImageGetColorSpace(image), 
    bitmapInfo: CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image), 
    version: UInt32(0), 
    decode: CGImageGetDecode(image), 
    renderingIntent: CGImageGetRenderingIntent(image))
```

This doesn't compile however. That's because `CGImageGetColorSpace(image)` returns `CGColorSpace!` and the above constructor only takes `Unmanaged<CGColorSpace>` for the `colorSpace` parameter.

Is there another way to do this? Perhaps converting `CGColorSpace` into `Unmanaged<CGColorSpace>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
vImage_CGImageFormat(
    // ...
    colorSpace: Unmanaged.passUnretained(CGImageGetColorSpace(image)),
    //...
)
```

From the `struct Unmanaged<T>` API documentation:

```
/// Create an unmanaged reference without performing an unbalanced
/// retain.
///
/// This is useful when passing a reference to an API which Swift
/// does not know the ownership rules for, but you know that the
/// API expects you to pass the object at +0.
///
/// ::
///
///   CFArraySetValueAtIndex(.passUnretained(array), i,
///                          .passUnretained(object))
static func passUnretained(value: T) -> Unmanaged<T>
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
vImage_CGImageFormat(
    // ...
    colorSpace: Unmanaged.passUnretained(image.colorSpace!),
    //...
)
```

Comment: You sir, are a gentlemen and a scholar